# Android mediaplayer (vitamio plugin) reset function noise

Tags: android, vitamio

I am using vitamio to play music in a list, when I switch to another song, I call Mediaplayer.reset(), but there is a noise in between before playing the next song.

the code like this:

```
mPlayer.reset();  //noise playing for a second
try {
mPlayer.setDataSource(station.getUrl());
mPlayer.prepareAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest calling `mPlayer.stop()` first.